# SharePoint 2013 REST API call Threshold limit

Tags: resource-throttling, sharepoint-rest-api

I am fetching data from a list using REST call. I have added filter query in the REST url also the the column on which filter operation id done is set as Indexed column in the list. The no of items returned is more than 5000, so it is throwing threshold/throttling error. is there any solution to overcome this apart from increasing the threshold value from CA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  in built SP Rest api  paging.
First limit the result = using top key
then you can page using data.d.__next key .
Sample snippet

```
function getReport() {
    $.ajax({
        url: queryUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            try {
                $(data.d.results).each(function(index) {
                   //process your logic
                });
                //Pagging
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    queryUrl = data.d.__next;
                    getReport();
                } else {                
                 //last page       
                }
            } catch (err2) {                 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err2));
            }
        },
        error: function(jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {            
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: ok...so if i put top=500 and assume filtered data is 5000, then it will iterate for 10 times and give me all 5000 data...is it like that..plz explain.

Comment: yeah , it will fetch

Comment: Incorrect: if you use $top=500, it will only return the first 500 results and will not have the __next variable there.